# My node js program is not getting my endpoints, thus cannot POST or GET

Tags: node.js, json, express

I'm still new to Node JS and doing an excercise but i'm having a problem restructuring my routes, controllers and models calls from a different servers. I've created 2 api routes for a "GET" /list to fetch a list ocf team members AND and POST: to add a json string to be used to calculate the sum of values in the json.
Running my mathsServer runs independently fine, but i want to call the maths function from the apiServer instead, but now getting my endpoints.
Program starts as follows: Web-app.js --> apiServer.js (apiController, apiModel, apiRoutes)-->mathsServer.js-->apiServer.js

My code is as follows:
Web-app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const apiRoute  = require('./apiServer/apiRoutes');
const app = express();

const host = "127.0.0.1"
const port = 3000

app.use('/list', apiRoute);
app.use('/add', apiRoute);
    
app.listen(port, host, () => {
    console.log(`The server is running at: http://${host}:${port}`);
});
```

apiServer.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const mathsServer = require('../mathServer');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 

const app = express();

const host = "127.0.0.1"
const port = 3000

app.use('/add', mathsServer.addTal); 

app.get('/list', (req, res) => {
    let teams = [];
    loadTeams()
      .then(function(data){   
        teams = data; 
        console.log(teams);  
            //res.send(data);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
      res.send("My root page");
      console.log(teams);
});

app.post('/add', (req, res) => {
    var sum = addera(req.body.tal);  
    console.log(sum);
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.listen(port, host, () => {
    console.log(`The server is running at: http://${host}:${port}`);
});
```

apiServer-model.js:

```
function loadTeams() {
    fs.readFile('prov-nodes.json', (err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        let teams = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(teams);
    });
    
    console.log('This is after the read call');
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    let teams = [];
    loadTeams()
      .then(function(data){   
        teams = data; 
        console.log(teams);  
            //res.send(data);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
      res.send("My root page");
      console.log(teams);
});
```

apiController.js

```
    onst apiServer = require("../model/apiServer-model");
    
    const teamList = (req, res) => {
        loadTeams()
        .then(function (data) {
            res.send(data);
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
    
    module.exports = {
        teamList
    }

apiRoutes.js

    const express = require('express');
    const apiController = require('./controllers/apiController');
    const mathsServer = require('../mathServer/mathsServer');
    const router = express.Router();
    
    router.get('/list', (req, res) => {
        apiController.teamList;
    })
    
    router.post('/add', (req, res) => {
        mathsServer.addera;
    });

module.exports = router;
```

mathsServer.js

```
    const express = require('express');
    const math = require('mathjs');
    const fetch = require('node-fetch');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    
    const app = express();

   /*
    const host = "127.0.0.1"
    const port = 3000 */
    
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    
    function addera(tal) {
        let strNumbersArr = tal.split(","); // ["10", "343", "24", ..., "233"]
        let sum = 0;
        for(let i = 0; i < strNumbersArr.length; i++) {
            let currentNumberStr = strNumbersArr[i];
        sum += Number(currentNumberStr); // convert current number string into a number
        }
        return sum;
    }
    
    app.post('/add', (req, res) => {
        var sum = addera(req.body.tal);  
        console.log(sum);
    });


    app.listen(port, host, () => {
        console.log(`The server is running at: http://${host}:${port}`);
    });
```

ERROR MESSAGE:
- Cannot GET /list  (http://127.0.0.1:3000/list 404 (Not Found))
- Cannot POST /add  (http://127.0.0.1:3000/add 404 (Not Found))

Comment: Your apiServer.js does not export anything thus `const apiServer  = require('./apiServer');` is the same as `const apiServer = undefined`. Since the variable `apiServer` is undefined doing `app.use('/', apiServer)` is the same as `app.use('/', undefined)`

Comment: @slebetman, thanks for your prompt reply. So is it fine to write e.g. **app.use('/', apiServer.get)**, or how do i get the Web-app.js to invoke the routes in apiServer.js?

Comment: @slebetman, I  have re-adjusted my program, now running, but not getting my endpoints, thus cannot POST or GET.

Comment: Fixing everything wrong with your program and answering all you need to know to get this running requires at least two chapters of a book if not an entire book. I strongly suggest you follow an Express tutorial and a simple tutorial on node.js modules (I'd suggest first learning about Commonjs modules used with `require` and then ES6 modules used with `import` mainly because Commonjs modules are simpler to understand)

Comment: @slebetman, Thanks anyway. I'll do the tuturials.